# How to get the String or Value of a selected JRadioButton?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that will take some information from the user and store it. So far it went well, but now I found myself unable to collect the string or value from a group of radio buttons.

I want that the button that the user selects my program will get the string from it.
I just started java so I would apriciate if someone could help me out.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Lab_11_1_Question_1 extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel text1 = new JLabel("Name: ");
    private JLabel text2 = new JLabel("Surname: ");
    private JLabel text3 = new JLabel("Departament: ");
    private JLabel text4 = new JLabel("Gender: ");
    private JTextField textfield1 = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField textfield2 = new JTextField(10);
    private JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Female");
    private JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("Male");
    private JComboBox<String> box1 = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]
    { "Computer Engineering", "Civil Engineering", "Mining Engineering" });
    private JButton button1 = new JButton("List");
    private JButton button2 = new JButton("Add");

    Lab_11_1_Question_1()
    {
        super("Manage Students");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 5, 5));
        add(text1);
        add(textfield1);
        add(text2);
        add(textfield2);
        add(text3);
        add(box1);
        add(text4);
        ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
        group1.add(radio1);
        group1.add(radio2);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 5, 5));
        panel1.add(radio1);
        panel1.add(radio2);
        add(panel1);
        add(button1);
        add(button2);

        MyClass listener = new MyClass();

        button1.addActionListener(listener);
        button2.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public class MyClass implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            if (e.getSource() == button2)
            {
                String name = textfield1.getText();
                String surname = textfield2.getText();
                String departament = (String) (box1.getSelectedItem());
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Lab_11_1_Question_1 frame = new Lab_11_1_Question_1();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `radio1.getText()`?

This method is declared in `javax.swing.AbstractButton`. See the Java doc for more details: [JRadioButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) and [AbstractButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html).

Comment: The thing is i have 2 Radio Buttons on a group, and i want the text for the one that the user will select.

Comment: Then you can add a change listener to the button: radio1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
  
  @Override
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
   System.out.println(radio1.isSelected());
  }
 });

Comment: Actually, you just gave me a better idea. I will just use the radio1.isSelected(); if (true)radio1.getText();
I guess that would be shorter and less of a pain. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yes it worked. I just casted some if conditions using the .isSelected(); method and then if true .getText(); It worked perfectly! Thanks!